# Placing a path to an image in mySQL and displaying on a php page in dreamweaver

Tags: php, mysql, dreamweaver

For my uni project i have created a website for my local rugby team...
I have a database of players and in that database i have a column for profile picture. I was told to just put the path to the image in the player record which i did. The photo doesnt load just the line i put it there. The path i inserted below....
H:\WebDesign2\Xampp\htdocs\BedlinogRFC\images\Benji.jpg
Below is my dreamweaver code:

```
    <div class="playerProfilePhotoContainer">
    <table height="250" width="299" border="0" cellpadding="3">
      <caption>
        Player Photo
      </caption>
      <tr>
        <td><img src="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['ProfilePhoto']; ?>" alt="Profile Photo of Player"/></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Can anybody show me where i am going wrong or where i need to change?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
<td height="235"><?php echo $row_Recordset1['ProfilePhoto']; ?></td>
```

Should be:

```
<td height="235"><img src="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['ProfilePhoto']; ?>" alt=""/></td>
```

Comment: Thanks i input the changes above and added the alt text. When loading the page to my browser im just getting the alt text?

Comment: is my path correct or do i need to add anything? i have saved the profile photo column as a VARCHAR(512) latin1_swedish_ci  . . Is that correct?

Comment: Seems that the images aren't being found? Have you checked that the images exist in `said` location with the path that you stored in the database?

Comment: @FunksterPhillipWatkins it's telling you what to do. Look into [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [`MySQLi`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) & also, I've never worked with Dreamweaver before so I can't comment on its save path.

Comment: sorted the save path now... Thanks will check that now cheers.

Comment: @FunksterPhillipWatkins All good mate, let me know if you need more help.

Comment: I still cant get the image to display on my screen. I have edited my code above. I think its right now. This is my image path - H:\WebDesign2\Xampp\htdocs\BedlinogRFC\images\Benji.jpg in a VARCHAR(255) column ... The photo is in that folder. Im totally lost as to what to do ive searched everywhere for last 3 days.

Comment: @FunksterPhillipWatkins Do you have a local server running to serve the php files up properly?

Comment: Yes mate. I am display all the other information in the table fine. Its only the images i cant get to display. Has the images got to be in a specific folder? I have them inside my websites images folder within htdocs?

Comment: @FunksterPhillipWatkins What's the directory structure like. Have you tried absolute and relative paths to include the images?

Comment: yeah tried both now and still no joy. I have tried putting images in different folders too but still no joy. I have found a way around my problem though. I have linked url's to images and they display fine. Thanks for all your help mate. Its much appreciated!!